# D3 function(d,i) callback skips first item

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have very strange problem with D3. It is skipping the first item in data array.

I have very simple code

```
function getRandomValue(from, to) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from;
}

var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  data.push(getRandomValue(0, 1000));
}

var getValueCallback = (item) => item;

var domain = [
  d3.min(data, getValueCallback),
  d3.max(data, getValueCallback)
];
var colors = [];

var colorRange = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(domain)
  .range(['red', 'blue']);

var ticks = colorRange.ticks(5);

var legend = d3.select('g.legend')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(ticks)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend-item');

var height = 100;
var rectW = 20;
var rectH = 20;

legend.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 20)
  .attr('y', (d, i) => height - ((i + 2) * rectH))
  .attr('width', rectW)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .style('fill', (d, i) => colorRange(d));
```

which works perfectly fine on jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/klinki/k0m4p6b3/

but doesn't work in my application.
http://klinki.cz/floorplan/angular/viewer.html

(It is pretty much the same code, as you can see here: )

http://klinki.cz/floorplan/angular/dist/js/app/Components/HeatmapScale/HeatmapScale.js

My application is using jQuery, Angular2, RxJS and bunch of other libraries (mostly Angular2 dependencies).

<del>I guess some of those libraries must somehow interfere with D3, but I have no idea which one could cause such a problem :(</del>

Update:

It's my fault, I missed differences in svg code which were causing problems. Sorry Angular 2 for blaming you for those issues :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selection is wrong:

```
var legend = d3.select('g.legend')
  .selectAll('g')//get all group with .legend 
  .data(ticks)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend-item');
```

This will select the group and bind the first data to it:

```
<g class="heatmap"></g>
```

now for the rest of the data it will make groups with class `legend-item`

The correct way should be:

```
var legend = d3.select('g.legend')
  .selectAll('legend-item')
  .data(ticks)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend-item');
```

In jsfiddle you don't have a group  `<g class="heatmap"></g>` inside legend so it works.

Hope this resolves your problem :)

Comment: Such a stupid mistake :D Thank you! I was too focused on javascript code so I didn't realize the SVG code is not same :)

Comment: yeah i know you blamed angular 2 :)

Comment: I will update my original post and cross out the angular2 blaming part :) I guess I should get more sleep and not be working too late at night :)